# Using Hibernate doesn't trigger MySQL's "ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP"

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa

In a MySQL DB every table has a column `updated` which is created as

```
[...] `updated` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
```

As expected, every row update does trigger the timestamp's update to the CURRENT_TIMESTAMP. This is true when I update a row via the SQL shell, command line, DBeaver, Workbench **BUT**

Working with Hibernate (Spring Boot 2, Spring Data JPA) does not work. I mean, pseudocode such as:

```
[Tx]
entity = repository.findById(1) --> Returns my entity with updated == 1L 
entity.setProperty("other value")
repository.save(entity)
[/Tx]
```

At this point, the DB entry has been updated ("other value" is the current value) but the `updated` column is still 1L where should be CURRENT_TIMESTAMP

I used to bypass this problem either

- annotating the property as `@UpdateTimestamp`or h
- annotating a method with @PrePersist && @PreUpdate which would programatically set the current timestamp before the `UPDATE` SQL statement

The problem with both approaches is that I don't have the updated value until out of my Tx:

```
[Tx]
entity.getUpdated() == 1L
entity.setName("other")
repository.save(entity) // at this point the updated is still == 1L
repository.findById()  // at this point the updated is still == 1L
[/Tx]

[Tx]
repository.findById()  // good timestamp value
[Tx]
```

Is it normal that MySQL doesn't trigger the update in the first place?

Is there a way to fetch the updated value in the same transaction?

Comment: Can you run `SHOW CREATE TABLE yourTable` and check whether this timestamp column in fact has an `ON UPDATE` clause?  I suspect that it may not.

Comment: Yes it does for sure. As said in the question, when using command line or an SQL IDE such as DBeaver, the update takes place. It's only when going through JPA that this doesn't work (potentially other frameworks but this I can't be sure)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need [JPARepository.saveAndFlush()](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-save-saveandflush) (or with raw JPA, `EntityManager.refresh()`) to get the updated value from the database in the same transaction. This affects all database generated values.

JPA doesn't know that values are changing inside the database, and it would be bad for performance to always re-read the saved value. That's why in a new transaction you get the correct values, as the data is actually fetched from the database. In the same transaction the value is still in memory and assumed to be unchanged.

Comment: Well, that actually works as long as I manually do the update via annotations (@Prepersist @PreUpdate or @UpdatedTimestamp)

Comment: @luso those are not database generated values. They're generated on the Java side. I explained why database generated values aren't seen in the same transaction.

Comment: Yes, I understood that. Actually either DB generated (on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) or Hibernate generated (annotations) are updated unless I saveAndFlush(). That's working now, thank you! If I get rid of annotations however, the MySQL trigger still doesn't trigger. But then I thinks is because Hibernate adds the "updated" field in the query to the current value even if it didn't change, and this prevents MySQL to override it.

Comment: @luso ah yes, you need to tune the `insertable` and `updatable` parameters of `@Column`, and possibly use Hibernate's `@Generated` on the column if those aren't enough.